# action of orthogonal group on the space of antisymmetric bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

What is the natural action of orthogonal group on the space of antisymmetric bilinear forms.

Comment: Well, elements of $O(n)$ are a group of $n \times n$ matrices. Antisymmetric bilinear forms on an $n$-dimensional vector space are another collection  $n \times n$ matrices. The action is matrix multiplication, but you have to use the definitions of "orthogonal" and  "antisymmetric" to make sure the action makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^T A = A A^T = I,$ and $B^T = -B,$ then
$$ C = A^T B A  $$
also satisfies $C^T = -C.$

Oh, the bilinear form is $v,w \mapsto v^T B w.$ The important detail is that a 1 by 1 matrix is a number and is its own transpose.